# using gstreamer 1.6 qt sinks

Tags: qt, gstreamer

I am trying to run the example that can be found here using gstreamer 1.6.4 on my ARM based board (https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/tests/examples/qt/qml)

I have Qt 5.5.1 installed and I have built gstreamer 1.6.4 and all the relevant plugins but when I run the example, it cannot find the GLVideoItem component and comes back with:

```
qrc:/main.qml:7 module "org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GLVideoItem" is not installed
```

Now, my question is how can I check if this component is installed on my system?

Also, do I need to rebuild qt linking against the new installation of gstreamer to be able to use this component?

**[EDIT]**

I also noticed creating `qmlglsink` element as `get_element_factory_make("qmlglsink", NULL)` returns NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From shell:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 qmlglsink
```

I would check the ldd on your app of which GStreamer is used (if you have some system GStreamer and compiled one).. then you will have to set proper paths to pick the proper one.

```
ldd ./your-app | grep -i gst
```

Notice the PKGCONFIG in your .pro file (in the tutorial you linked) - you may check what is pkg config thinking about that:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0
```

Comment: This was because the gstreamer-bad plugin was not being built with qt support. It got sorted by compiling the plugins correctly.